# Cross Reference TSQL Join

Tags: t-sql

Say i have Four tables

1) Studnets:

- Student_ID
- First Name
- Last Name

2) Contact (Will take the latest item)

- Contact_ID
- Address
- ZipCode
- DateAdded

3) Phone (Will take the last three items)

- Contact_ID
- PhoneNumber
- DateAdded

4) StudentContactRef

- Student_ID
- Contact_ID

How can I query this table?  I want to have the fields as shows below:

- Student_ID
- First Name
- Last Name
- Address
- ZipCode
- PhoneNumber1
- PhoneNumber2
- PhoneNumber3

Comment: Your tables would be much easier to query if you could make the Phone have a Phone_Contact_ID as distinct from the Contact_ID... or if you could add a 'type' field to the StudentContactRef table to indicate if you are linking to a Contact or a Phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    s.Student_ID,
    s.FirstName,
    s.LastName,
    c.Contact_ID,
    c.Address,
    c.ZipCode,
    p.PhoneNumber1,
    p.PhoneNumber2,
    p.PhoneNumber3
from
    Students s
    inner join StudentContactRef r on
        s.Student_ID = r.StudentID
    inner join Contact c on
        r.Contact_ID = c.Contact_ID
    inner join
        (select top 3 Contact_ID, PhoneNumber from Phone 
         pivot (PhoneNumber for PhoneNumber IN 
             (PhoneNumber1, PhoneNumber2, PhoneNumber3) 
         where Contact_ID = r.Contact_ID order by DateAdded desc) p on
        r.Contact_ID = p.Contact_ID
```

Update: That should get you what you're looking for!